# Deducing a $\frac{Dv}{Dt}$=$\frac{∂v}{∂t}$+$\frac{1}{2}$∇ (|v|$^2$) for an irrotational flow.

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

A flow has been defined in my textbook as irrotational if skew(∇v(x, t)) ≡ 0, i.e. if the velocity gradient is a symmetric tensor.

An exercise left at the end of the chapter tasks one to deduce $\frac{Dv}{Dt}$ = $\frac{∂v}{∂t}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$ $∇(|v|^2$) given a irrotational flow.

I have attached what I have done so far.
[image]

I'm confused as to what what I'm doing wrong, I'm pretty sure what I've written at the bottom is correct but it doesn't really tell me much. Is there any way I can use the property of an irrotational flow better to get the desired result? I feel like I ought to use what I know about acceleration to write v. ($∇$)v in terms of skew(∇)v as then we could to simplify the problem further by using the property of an irrotational flow, I'm just unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution given by ryaron is clever but overly complicated. The result can be very easily obtained using the product rule and the symmetry of the deformation tensor.

Let $\mathbf D=\nabla\boldsymbol u$ be the velocity gradient or deformation tensor. We say that $\boldsymbol u$ is *irrotational* if $\nabla\times \boldsymbol u=0$, which in turn implies that $\mathbf D$ is symmetric.

Now, note that the components of the convective acceleration can be given by
$$\big((u\cdot \nabla)u\big)^i=u^j\nabla_j u^i=u_j\nabla^ju^i=u_j(\nabla u)^{ij}=u_jD^{ij}$$

> Recall that $(\nabla v)_{ij}=\nabla_jv_i$, **NOT** $\nabla_iv_j$ !!

On the other hand,
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\nabla(| u|^2)\right)^i=\frac{1}{2}\nabla^i(u^ju_j) \\ =\frac{1}{2}u^j\nabla^iu_j+\frac{1}{2}u_j\nabla^iu^j\\ =u_j\nabla^iu^j \\ =u_jD^{ji}$$

However, when $\mathbf D$ is symmetric, $D^{ji}=D^{ij}$, and hence $(\boldsymbol u\cdot \nabla)\boldsymbol u=\frac{1}{2}\nabla (|\boldsymbol u|^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I follow the convention to call the velocity "u". But it's still clear.

Answer (score 0):

An irrotational flow implies:

$\nabla\times v=0$

Take the tensor identity:

$v\times\nabla\times v\implies \\
\epsilon_{ijk}v_j\epsilon_{klm}\frac{\partial v_l}{\partial x_m}=$

$(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl})v_j\frac{\partial v_l}{\partial x_m}=0$

Since, $\nabla\times v=0$.

Eventually we receive:

$v_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}-v_j\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}=0$

From which we deduce:

$(v\cdot\nabla)v-\frac{1}{2}\nabla(|v|^2)=0$

Comment: This requires one to prove $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{lmk}=\delta^l_i\delta^m_j-\delta^m_i\delta^l_j$ which is not exactly easy.

Comment: @K.defaoite I see, as the answer that's been written says, I do have difficulty with coordinate algebra but I would appreciate some help on this as I'm currently unable to show this. The rest makes sense apart from showing $v_j \frac{∂v_j}{∂x_i}=\frac{1}{2} ∇(|v|^2)$.

Comment: $v_j\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial (v_j^2)}{\partial x_i}$ in coordinate free notation you get the result (summation convention applies).

Comment: To prove: $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}=(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl})$ use the determinant of the matrix of $\{\delta_{ij}\}$